# How can I check the maximum amount of RAM my laptop motherboard can support?

Tags: laptop, memory, lenovo-laptop

I have a 2013 Lenovo G580 with a 3230M i5 and 1x4GB 1600MHz RAM. I'm planning to upgrade the RAM to 12GB by putting in an 8GB RAM module. However, I do not know if my motherboard supports more than 8GB of RAM (it does have a free slot for more RAM though). How can I check if it does?

Also, will I lose out on the dual channel benefits if I put it in an 8GB-1600 instead of a 4GB-1600 module?

Answer (score 1):

According to [NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834312518), your notebook can only support 8GB. In order to get the benefits of dual channel, both memory modules need to be the same size and speed. (The match pairs almost always work, whereas mismatched modules tend not to work).

Comment: This is correct, but why reference a reseller's web page when you can reference the (more authoritative) original Web page of the manufacturer? Here: http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/essential/g-series/g580/#tab-tech_specs

Comment: @MariusMatutiae When I indicated what model of laptop I was searching for, it stated it was no longer being sold and made it difficult to get the information I wanted; so I went to another site. It was just for convenience.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Finally, my laptop uses Hynix RAM, but it seems only Transcend modules are available on amazon. Will 4GB-1600 transcend ram activate dual-channel mode?

Comment: I'm not certain that will work. For dual channel to operate, the memory needs to be the same configuration, speed and latency. According to Kingston Technology, their memory (Part Number: KTL-TP3BS/4G) should work.